# What values can be held by the access attribute of intercept-url?

Tags: java, spring

[**In the spring-security example**](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/) I came across with the following tag:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

So I guess we can specify any role the specified url-pattern may be accessible. My question is is `hasRole('ROLE_NAME')` the only pattern that can be assigned to the `access` attribute. Or we can specify something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hasRole(ROLE_NAME)` is so called *Expression-Based Access Control* which has been introduced from the ***3.0*** release of Spring Security.

The expression defined in the `access` attribute allows complex boolean instruction to be evaluated and used along with the simple configuration attributes.

There is already many built-in expressions ready to use besides the `hasRole([role])` such as:

- `hasAnyRole([role1,role2,...])`
- `isAnonymous()`
- `isAuthenticated()`...

More can be found under the [*el-access* chapter of the Spring Security Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html).